# If $a^n, b^n$ and $c^n$ form a triangle for all $n \in \Bbb N$, prove that the triangles are isosceles.

Tags: induction, triangles

> If $a^n, b^n$ and $c^n$ form a triangle for all $n \in \Bbb N$, prove that the triangles are isosceles given that $a\geq b\geq c> 0$.

I started on the lines of $a< b+c$. But no idea how to proceed further. Tried using cosine law, but no help.

Comment: How exactly do $a^n,b^n,c^n$ form a triangle?

Comment: @RhysHughes Triangular inequality

Comment: Hint: if $a>b>c>0$, then $c^n$ is growing slower than $a^n-b^n$

Comment: Also recently asked and answered: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2780470/42969.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
Look at the possible values of
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{b^n+c^n}{a^n}$$

Answer (score 0):

let's assume, wolog $a\ge b \ge c$.

To be a triangle we need $c^n > a^n - b^n =(a-b)(a^n + a^{n-1}b + .... + ab^{n-1} + b^n)$

If $a = b$ this is always true but if $a \ne b$. Then:

we need $c^n > a^n - b^n =$

$(a-b)(a^n + a^{n-1}b + .... + ab^{n-1} + b^n) > $

$(a-b)(a^n)$ or in other words we need

$a-b > \frac {c^n}{a^n} = (\frac ca)^n$.

but $0< \frac ca < 1$ so $\lim_{n\to \infty } (\frac ca)^n = 0$.

Which means there is an $N$ so that $(\frac ca)^N < a-b$.

So it is not possible for all $n$ for $a-b > (\frac ca)^n$.

So $a \ne b$ is impossible and $a = b$.

Comment: Whoops.. you were given the inequalities in the *exact* opposite order.  Let me reedit.

Comment: Understood. All this time I was trying to find a way to prove b=c. As they were the smaller numbers.

Comment: Actually I wasn't sure where the proof would go and hearing the question I thought it'd have to do with the smaller sides too.  But the proof went where it wanted to go.  And in hindsight its obvious, but there is something that intuitively look for the smaller sides. not sure what it is.